# CON1 to USB connector cable

Tags: usb, connector, identification, low-power

I have a board which has a CON1 connector being currently used for a battery. Are all CON1 ports serial? Why would a battery need a CON1 port?

My guess is, this port can be used to interface and debug the board. Where can I buy a suitable cable?

[photo http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5756/serialb.png](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/5756/serialb.png)

EDIT: Sorry, the port is called CON1. The print was really small.

Comment: What is the name and make of the board?

Comment: That image shows a small 4-pin Molex connector, which looks like it carries power (guessing based on wire colour). I was expecting a 9-pin D-subminature connector when you said "COM1"!

Comment: basic serial link only needs rx and tx signals, when generic connection also add vcc and gnd. COM ports could drive modems which need more signals. If this cable is used to supply power, then i guess only red and black wire are used.

Comment: The board is a proprietary board from Seagate called Satellite_V2R4. And I'm sorry I misread the fine-print. It says CON1 on the board where this wire fits in. So this isn't the way to go then?

Comment: There are no standard for such things.  The question is not answerable without more information, such as documentation, personal experience, or tracing the signals back to source chips.

Comment: Oh CON rather than COM! It's just a battery connector. If you're looking for a back door into the board, there might be JTAG somewhere; a couple of large clear photos of both sides might allow someone to spot something useful.

Comment: Since the board is proprietary, I lack the documentation. I know of someone went through the board with an oscillator and there were no other serial interfaces. I ripped it open, and this was the only likely candidate I came across.

Comment: I will try to take a photograph of the board for you. Here's an older version of the board: http://images.anandtech.com/doci/4706/Screen%20Shot%202011-11-13%20at%204.20.09%20AM.png

Comment: Assuming there is no JTAG, how would a manufacturer flash bootloader and kernel onto a board?

Comment: @user1958761 - parts could be preprogrammed before installation.  Many microcontrollers have a mask rom bootloader from the factory, though utilizing that would require a communication channel.  Your connector could be a serial interface.  Some of the gold plated test points around the board could be jtag or other signals for use with a spring-pin production fixture.

Answer (score 2):

CON1 undoubtedly stands for Connector 1, which is an arbitrary label on the board used to refer to the given connector. It has no specific meaning outside of "This is the first connector", in the same way R1 is used for the first Resistor, Q1 for the first Transistor, TP1 for the first Test Point, etc.

Seeing the picture that the OP provided in the comments, this is the most obvious answer.

[image: User's Board]